# Exception Thrown in thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I have a thread pool and I use a library that if certain conditions are met to throw an exception. My question is if this runs out of the IDE, will the thread come to an halt or will the whole entire program come to a halt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application is .Net 2+, an unhandled exception on a non-main thread will flatten the process.

You can configure this behavior using the app.config `LegacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy` setting, but I wouldn't recommend this as it potentially masks serious bugs.

**Update**

If you wish to ignore the occasional timeout exception, consider placing your WebService call in a try\catch block and ignore the timeout exception:

```
try
{
    //Call WebService
}
catch(System.Net.WebException ex)
{
   //Ignore
}
```

Comment: @Joe Could you please explain why you would want to kill the thread. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: +1 LegacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy looks like it would do exactly what the OP wants

Comment: @Chibacity I am using a webservice that may time out. I do this multiple times a day miss a couple calls here and there, opposed to having the system come to a crashing out is much more desirable.

Comment: @Joe Can you not place the code calling the WebService in a try\catch that will catch timeout exceptions and ignore them?

Comment: @Chibacity I added a try catch in my code and removed the throwexception from deep in the library I was using.

Answer (score 3):

So lets review what you have:

- You have a method executing on a `TheadPool` thread.
- This method will throw an exception.
- The exception will not be handled by a `try-catch` block.
- The application is running outside of the IDE.

Now we can easily test this with the following code. Pay careful attention to the observations below, especially the bold one, because they are interesting in the context of your question.

```
public static void Main()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        (state) =>
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }, null);

    while (true)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

When running outside of the IDE you will observe the following.

- A dialog box will appear saying "[application] has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."
- **The application will continue to run and print the current time each second.**
- The application will terminate *after* clicking Close on the dialog box.

When running inside the IDE<sup>1</sup> you will observe the following.

- The IDE will intercept the exception and display it using its own unhandled exception window.
- All threads will be halted which means you will not see the current time being displayed.
- Ignoring the exception and resuming the debugging session will allow the current time to begin displaying.
- The IDE will again rethrow the exception and intercept it.
- All threads will be halted and the cycle will repeat indefinitely.

---

<sup>1</sup>I tested this with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

When the debugger breaks a program, all threads come to a halt.

In the `Debug -> Windows -> Threads` screen, you can see the threads.  You can "freeze" a thread, which means it will stay halted if you continue running the program.

So it is possible to keep some threads halted even when the debugger runs.  The opposite is not possible: no thread can run when the debugger is in break mode.

Comment: so what happens when it is out in the real world?

Comment: @Joe Tyman: Ah, so by "out of the IDE" you mean "outside the IDE" :)  In the real world the program will crash, and Windows will present the user with a dialog.  You can prevent this in three ways: 1) `try ... catch` blocks in all threads; 2) the LegacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy setting; 3) if you run as a Windows service exceptions in threads will not kill the program